# Distinguishing a generic man-page and an implementation-specific man-page?

Tags: manpage, abstraction-layer

I have written a suite of programs that is supposed to work on both MacOS X and on GNU/Linux. For most components, the code is identical for both MacOS X and for GNU/Linux - however there are a few low-level commands for which (based on auto-detection) the installer will install an implementation of the tool specific to your operating system - which (as I said) is for the time being either MacOS X or GNU/Linux.

The thing is - for these low-level commands that have different implementations for different systems, each command will require two man-pages to be installed - one which describes the usage and behavior of the command independently of what system/implementation you are using - and another which merely documents specifics for the specific system's implementation of the command.

So my question is -- does the **man** command offer a way to distinguish between two such man-pages? And if so, what is it?

I already have a solution for when you access the man-pages through the command's own **--help** option (basically, that the generic man-page is what you see when you invoke the command with the **--help** option itself - yet the generic man-page includes instructions as to what option will display the implementation-specific man-page) but I'm now getting to the part where I will be writing the capability for the program's installer to install the man-pages where they can actually be accessed through the **man** command, and therefore, where these low-level commands are concerned, I need to know if there is a way to distinguish between these two distinct man-pages for the same command.